# Problem with reading from a json file when refreshing th page Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have an angular application and the client wants the path of the Backend in a json file, so he can change it easily whithout needing of another deployment.

Well i did it, but when i refresh the page or close the app and reopen it, the app don't detect the path of the backend, it is like a problem of retard or synchronisation.

This is the error in the console :

```
 http://***/undefinedapi/Leave/GetlistLeave
```

This is how i did it :
The json file :

```
    {
      "ApiRoot": "http://***/"
    }
```

How i read from the constant from the json file :

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
     import { apiRoot } from '../model/model.apiRoot';
     import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

     @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
     })
     export class apiRootService {
    static apiRoot: string;
     constructor(private http: Http) { }
     public initialiseApiRoot()
     {

         this.http.get('./assets/apiRoot/apiRoot.json').pipe(map((response: Response) => 
      <apiRoot>response.json())).subscribe(data => {
          apiRootService.apiRoot = data['ApiRoot'];
      })

     }
   }
```

and then i call this function in the constructor of app.component.ts like this :

```
        this.apiRootService.initialiseApiRoot();
```

and change the call of the api in every servic elike this :

```
       return this.http.get(apiRootService.apiRoot + .....
```

Any hlp and thanks

Comment: where is the first part `http://***/` in your error message ` http://***/undefinedapi/Leave/GetlistLeave` coming from? is this the old api that is not replaced? because I would thought if your JSON file is not parsed and used the error message would be `undefinedapi/Leave/GetlistLeave`. What I'm trying to say is: are there other variabled you include here `return this.http.get(apiRootService.apiRoot + .....` that might be the actual cause of the problem?

Comment: `apiRootService.apiRoot` should be `this.apiRoot`

Comment: And it may be possible your other API is being called before the success of read of json file

Comment: @kenny i made it as ** so i don't show my backEnd URL and like i u said the API is being called before the succes of read of json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's suppose you're not facing a cache problem. If it isn't a cache problem, maybe it's a matter of timing.

You can try to set your `apiRoot` while your app is initializing (before `app.component.ts` is loaded). You can do that by providing an `APP_INITIALIZER` as described [in Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers). If you use a factory that returns a function providing a promise, you'll delay your app initialization until your json file is loaded so you can initialize `apiRoot`. A factory is a useful approach because it will allow you to inject `HttpClient` service during initialization in the provider (you'll need it to get your json file).

You can do something like (in your `app.module.ts`):

```js
...
import {APP_INITIALIZER} from '@angular/core';
...

// Angular will inject the HttpClient because you'll 
// tell it that this is a dependency of this factory
// in the providers array 
export function getApiRoot(http: HttpClient) {
  return () => {
    return this.http.get('./assets/apiRoot/apiRoot.json').pipe(
      map((response: Response) => <apiRoot>response.json()),
      tap((data: any) => apiRootService.apiRoot = data['ApiRoot'])
    ).toPromise();
  };
}

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    {
      provide: APP_INTIALIZER,
      useFactory: getApiRoot,
      multi: true,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
    ...
  ]

})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are going with wrong approach. you are seeting url after application is initialized. Refer :- https://medium.com/voobans-tech-stories/multiple-environments-with-angular-and-docker-2512e342ab5a. this will give general idea how to achieve build once and deploy anywhere